# How to make Apache Solr to use user created dictionary in a text file for its suggestion and spell check?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a text file with 100,000 English words.. I am using Apache Solr 4.6 . Now I want to use that word list text file for both suggestion and Spell check ..

How to achive this ?

In the internet search I found `FileBasedSpellChecker` component... But no detailed explanation about it was found...

Since I am very new to Solr , please explain me in detail.

The worldlist.txt looks like this ..

...
abandoner 
abandoners 
abandoning 
abandonment 
abandonments 
abandons 
abase
..

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to this subject, so you'll need to do some of your own homework -- everything you need is on the [Solr Wiki SpellCheck component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) page.

At a high level: Solr is very configurable, and you can achieve what you want through configuration.

You are indeed interested in the FileBasedSpellChecker -- again, see the above-referenced Wiki page. You simply need to configure the spellcheck component in your Solr instance to make use of the text file you'd like to use.

A sample configuration entry* within the spellcheck component might look like this:

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">worldlist</str>
  <str name="field">some-field-in-your-index</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">/path/to/worldlist.txt</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
```

*This is minimal and may not include everything you want/need for your use case. Hence, the need for you to familiarize yourself with all the configurable options around Solr and the spell checking component.

As a final point, understand that Solr doesn't serve up flat files; it works with search indexes. The spell check component permits you to reference a flat file, but operationally it will be converted to an index for use by Solr. This requires an index build, which can be constructed with a one-time request to the spell check request handler with **spellcheck.build=true** appended to the request.